# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-glue, apache-kafka-connect, avro

I am trying to configure the Confluent S3 Sink Connector to consume messages from a topic in my MSK cluster, and write them in Parquet files on S3.
It is required a Schema, like Confluent Schema, but a Confluent Platform and Confluent CLI are required, so I saw that it was possible to use the Glue Schema Registry: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-an-end-to-end-change-data-capture-with-amazon-msk-connect-and-aws-glue-schema-registry/

The problem is that I always get the following exception in the logs:

```
Error converting message value in topic 'events' partition 0 at offset 2012214 and timestamp 1697576912985: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error
```

I created a Schema Registry in AWS, testregistry1, and then tried with configuration:

```
"connector.class" = "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector"
"key.converter"                                 = "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
"key.converter.schemas.enable"                  = "true"
"key.converter.avroRecordType"                  = "GENERIC_RECORD"
"key.converter.region"                          = "eu-central-1"
"key.converter.registry.name"                   = "testregistry1"
"key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled"   = "true"
"value.converter"                               = "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter"
"value.converter.schemas.enable"                = "true"
"value.converter.avroRecordType"                = "GENERIC_RECORD"
"value.converter.region"                        = "eu-central-1"
"value.converter.registry.name"                 = "testregistry1"
"value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled" = "true"    

# S3
"topics"               = "events"
"flush.size"           = 10
"s3.region"            = eu-central-1
"s3.bucket.name"       = "my_bucket"
"s3.part.size"         = 26214400
"storage.class"        = "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage"
"format.class"         = "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat"
"partitioner.class"    = "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner"
"schema.compatibility" = "NONE"

# Authorization
"security.protocol"                                           = "SASL_SSL"
"sasl.mechanism"                                              = "AWS_MSK_IAM"
"sasl.jaas.config"                                            = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;"
"sasl.client.callback.handler.class"                          = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler"
"confluent.topic.consumer.security.protocol"                  = "SASL_SSL"
"confluent.topic.consumer.sasl.mechanism"                     = "AWS_MSK_IAM"
"confluent.topic.consumer.sasl.jaas.config"                   = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;"
"confluent.topic.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class" = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler"
"confluent.topic.producer.security.protocol"                  = "SASL_SSL"
"confluent.topic.producer.sasl.mechanism"                     = "AWS_MSK_IAM"
"confluent.topic.producer.sasl.jaas.config"                   = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;"
"confluent.topic.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class" = "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler"
```

I also tried setting the AWSKafkaAvroConnector as the key.converter, but I get the same error.

Complete logs:

```
2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] [2023-10-18 10:55:24,825] ERROR Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter', where consumed record is {topic='events', partition=6, offset=2316078, timestamp=1697626522632, timestampType=CreateTime}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter.toConnectData(AWSKafkaAvroConverter.java:118)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:545)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.exception.AWSSchemaRegistryException: Didn't find secondary deserializer.

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.SecondaryDeserializer.deserialize(SecondaryDeserializer.java:65)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeByHeaderVersionByte(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:150)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:114)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter.toConnectData(AWSKafkaAvroConverter.java:116)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] ... 18 more

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] [2023-10-18 10:55:24,825] ERROR Error converting message value in topic 'events' partition 6 at offset 2316079 and timestamp 1697626522815: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:547)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter.toConnectData(AWSKafkaAvroConverter.java:118)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:545)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.exception.AWSSchemaRegistryException: Didn't find secondary deserializer.

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.SecondaryDeserializer.deserialize(SecondaryDeserializer.java:65)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeByHeaderVersionByte(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:150)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:114)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter.toConnectData(AWSKafkaAvroConverter.java:116)

2023-10-18T12:55:24.000+02:00   [Worker-0b0153b89034ed426] ... 18 more
```

Update:

I have replaced the Glue Schema Registry with Confluent Registry in an EC2 instance. As an example, I added the schema from the official page: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#example-requests-format-and-valid-json with

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/test/versions -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json' -d '{"schema":"{\"type\": \"record\",\"name\": \"test\",\"fields\":[{\"type\": \"string\",\"name\": \"field1\"},{\"type\": \"int\",\"name\": \"field2\"}]}"}'
```

And it gets created, but in my connector, after trying to set the following properties:

```
"key.converter"                       = "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
"value.converter"                     = "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
"value.converter.schemas.enable"      = false
"value.converter.avroRecordType"      = "GENERIC_RECORD"
"value.converter.dataFormat"          = "JSON"
"value.converter.schema.registry.url" = "http://<ip>:8081"
```

I am still getting the Converting byte[] to Kafka error, but this time due to magic byte:

```
2023-10-25T16:39:35.000+02:00   [Worker-00b8ad4cf64746b30] Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1

2023-10-25T16:39:35.000+02:00   [Worker-00b8ad4cf64746b30] Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

The message that I am trying to send it is quite simple, with ./kafka-console-producer.sh, I send to my topic:

```
{"field1":"test4578_01","field2":1}
```

Comment: 1) Confluent Platform and CLI are not required. Not sure what documents mentioned this. 2) Read the full stacktrace? The real error is `Didn't find secondary deserializer`

Comment: Hi, regarding documentation, I saw in https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/using.html#starting-sr so I thought it was required to have both.

Comment: About secondary deserializer, I thout that the root cause was the Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data exception, and the Didn't find secondary deserializer was an attempt to try with other deserializar, instead of the main one. So the issue was the main deserializer from the converter.

Comment: Since you're using Glue Registry, then nothing related to Confluent is required, other than the S3 sink plugin. Otherwise, MSK published a recent blog about writing data to S3, I think, and this connector was not used

Comment: @OneCricketeer I saw some examples with JsonFormat, which work. But I need to write in Parquet files on S3, which needs a schema. I have only seen the link that I sent before, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-an-end-to-end-change-data-capture-with-amazon-msk-connect-and-aws-glue-schema-registry/ which is from 08 MAR 2023, so should be up to date.

Comment: I have not used Glue Registry, or its converters, so will be unable to help here. I have used Confluent AvroConverter with Avro payloads, and ParquetFormat is working fine there.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updated the message with my current error, where I am trying to use the Confluent Registry. But I still get the Converting Byte[] error. Maybe a missing parameter?

Comment: `JsonSchemaConverter` is not the same as `JsonConverter`. For the former, you're required to use Confluent Schema Registry rather than Glue. Otherwise, you need to use this class, not Confluent's https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/blob/master/jsonschema-kafkaconnect-converter/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/schemaregistry/kafkaconnect/jsonschema/JsonSchemaConverter.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The message that I am trying to send it is quite simple, with ./kafka-console-producer.sh

This isn't JSONSchema, it's just plain JSON, so doesn't interact with any Registry-associated Converter classes, thus why you see "Invalid Magic Byte", since the data [isn't serialized correctly](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format).

`ParquetFormat` requires a structured event with a schema (specifically, it uses Avro to build Parquet files with `parquet-avro` Java package).

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

I personally haven't tested JSON->Parquet, only Avro->JSON and Avro->Parquet, but you can see in the above blog that the JSON events need to look like `{"schema": ..., "payload": ...}` with `org.apache.kafka...JsonConverter` + `schemas.enable=true` property (the default), or otherwise you need to use `kafka-json-schema-console-producer` CLI command from Confluent Platform with `io.confluent...JsonSchemaConverter` + `schema.registry.url`